# boost::filesystem::create_directory threw a boost::filesystem::filesystem_error: Bad address

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-filesystem

The TL;DR of my code is the following:

```
server::server(boost::filesystem::path mappath) : mappath(mappath) {
    if(boost::filesystem::is_directory(mappath) && boost::filesystem::exists(mappath)) {
        // Do some stuff here
    } else {
        boost::filesystem::create_directory(mappath);
    }
}
```

The code works when `mappath` exists (barely, as I find Boost to be segfaulting in almost every function).
However, when it doesn't, it throws an exception with the message "Bad address".
When I print `mappath` via `std::cout`, it returns:

```
"/home/myusername/.testfolder/huni/ENTER YOUR TEXT HERE"
```

Which is correct.

Note that, when I try printing `mappath` *inside* the else statement, it segfaults.
I've deduced that something messes with `mappath` in either `is_directory` or `exists`, as there were no errors when printing *before* the `if` statement.

Comment: You might be looking for `boost::filesystem::create_directories`.  But that's just a guess since we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DrewDormann After replacing it with `create_directories`, it now segfaults where it threw the exception.

Comment: We can only guess what might be wrong with your program.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a minimal verifiable example, as I ran the code I posted myself, and it still errors.

Comment: Funny, I got "use of undeclared identifier 'server'" when I tried to run the code you posted.

Comment: I'd start with the simplest Boost program that you can make segfault, and then *figure out why that's happening*. There's probably a silent failure somewhere that's causing strange behavior.

Comment: Regardless, make that smallest program that fails and post the code here. One function isn't going to help others help you, unfortunately.

Comment: @T.C. Haha, very funny /s. That could've obviously been put in the `main` function instead. This is that smallest program that fails, I already said so. There's absolutely no documentation on why Boost fails with `Bad address`, if there were I would've known my problem by now.

Comment: What is the concrete error message? Which function throws `Bad address`?

Comment: It is said in the title that `create_directory` throws `filesystem_error` with the message `Bad address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out `Bad address` is a POSIX-specific error.

Also the reason I couldn't print `mappath` in the else clause of my `if` statement, was that `is_directory` was messing with the reference.
What it was actually doing I couldn't figure out.

So, I've switched from Boost to something that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a MCVE for myself. When the path does not exist, boost throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: No such file or directory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

because your program first checks if the path is a directory and then it checks if the path exists (correct).

When the path exists and it is a directory, the program runs without output and does nothing (correct).

When the path exists and is a file, boost throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: File exists
Aborted (core dumped)
```

because it can't create a directory (correct).

Hence your snippet does what it should do. Maybe you should change the order in your `if` statement and add a check to your `else`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class server {
public:
  server(boost::filesystem::path mappath) : mappath(mappath) {
    if(boost::filesystem::exists(mappath) && boost::filesystem::is_directory(mappath)) {
        // Do some stuff here
    } else if (!boost::filesystem::exists(mappath)) {
        boost::filesystem::create_directory(mappath);
    }
  }
private:
  boost::filesystem::path mappath;
};

int main() {
  server s("/path/test");
  return 0;
}
```

Now the program checks, if the path exists. If the path exists, the program checks if the path is a directory. If the path doesn't exist, the directory is created.

Comment: This doesn't explain `Bad address`

Comment: @Dan Joe: As I showed the presented code snippet doesn't throw `Bad address`. The code works as expected. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I tried your code and it threw `Bad address` for me.

Comment: @DanJoe: How do you compile the code? Which version of boost do you use? On which os do you work?